# Erro Segmentation fault ao dar print em array 2D - loop não tá enviando valores para array

Tags: c, c++

Eu não estou conseguindo entender o porquê desse erro, Segmentation fault. Erro de segmento, aparentemente.

Eu tenho um código em que o usuário vai enviando valores que são gravados em uma array. Essa array tem duas dimensões, a 2D terá duas casas, uma em que será guardado o número do item e a outra o número de unidades, cada item na 1D do array será um pedido. São 7 itens, por isso que o loop quebra se o usuário der um valor que não esteja entre 1-7. A cada loop p de pedidos é acrescentdo +1.
Aqui eu deixei o código simplificado, só para dar destaque à lógica para ser analisada:

```
int main()
{
    int cont;
    int p = 0;
    int compra[][2] = {{0,0}};

    for (cont=0; cont <= 7; cont=0) {
        printf("\n\nPedido %d\n", (p+1));
        printf("\nQual item você quer?\n%sItem ");
        scanf("%d", &cont);

        if(cont > 7 || cont < 1) break;
        compra[p][0] = cont;
        
        printf("\n\nQuantas unidades?\nUnidade(s): ");
        scanf("%d", &compra[p][1]);
        p++;
    }
    char produto[][100] = {
        "cachorro(s)-quente", 
        "X-salada(s)",
        "X-bacon(s)",
        "misto(s)",
        "prato(s) de salada",
        "garrafa(s) de água",
        "refrigerante(s)"
    };
```

Logo depois que todos os valores são enviados eu quero mostrar os valores assim:

```
    for (cont = 0; cont <= p-1; cont++) {
        int item = compra[cont][0];
        printf("\n %d %s;\n", 
        compra[cont][1], produto[(item-1)]);
    }
}
```

Eu tentei usar um loop, ele dá print no primeiro item mas dá erro de segmento e não dá print no resto.

E então eu larguei do loop e tentei assim para ver:

```
    printf("\n%s %d %s;\n", margem, 
        compra[0][1], produto[(compra[0][0]-1)]);
    printf("\n%s %d %s;\n", margem, 
        compra[1][1], produto[(compra[1][0]-1)]);
    printf("\n%s %d %s;\n", margem, 
        compra[2][1], produto[(compra[2][0]-1)]);
    printf("\n%s %d %s;\n", margem, 
        compra[3][1], produto[(compra[3][0]-1)]);
```

Mesma coisa. Tirei a parte onde o usuário envia os valores e deixei os itens da array compra prontos, ficando assim:

```
int main()
{
    int p = 4;
    int cont;
    int compra[][2] = {{3,4},{1,7},{7,2},{2,1}}; 
  
    char produto[][100] = {
        "cachorro(s)-quente", 
        "X-salada(s)",
        "X-bacon(s)",
        "misto(s)",
        "prato(s) de salada",
        "garrafa(s) de água",
        "refrigerante(s)"
    };
    
    for (cont = 0; cont <= p-1; cont++) {
        int item = compra[cont][0];
        printf("\n %d %s;\n", 
        compra[cont][1], produto[(item-1)]);
    }
}
```

E funciona, então, provavelmente o erro que está causando o Segmentation Fault está naquele trecho que eu tirei, eu suspeito que o loop não esteja enviando os valores somente modificando o que já foi preenchido, mas por quê?

Edit:

E mais, quando eu faço a mesma coisa que em cima, porém, acrescentando um scanf para enviar mais um item à array, dá o mesmo erro, mesmo sem o loop.

O problema está nesse scanf?

Comment: Quantas compras queres guardar no máximo?

Comment: É indefinido. Não dá para deixar indefinido?

Answer (score 0):

O problema está em não definir o tamanho da primeira dimensão do array `compra` como estás a inicializar o mesmo ele apenas terá espaço para uma compra. Tens duas hipóteses ou indicas um tamanho para ele ou usas memória dinâmica.

Neste exemplo indico que no máximo vou ter 10 compras.

```c
int main(void) {
  int cont;
  int p;
  int compra[10][2];

  for(p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
    printf("\n\nPedido %d\n", (p+1));
    printf("\nQual item você quer?\nItem ");
    scanf("%d", &cont);

    if(cont > 7 || cont < 1) break;
    compra[p][0] = cont;
    
    printf("\n\nQuantas unidades?\nUnidade(s): ");
    scanf("%d", &compra[p][1]);
  }

  char produto[][100] = {
    "cachorro(s)-quente", 
    "X-salada(s)",
    "X-bacon(s)",
    "misto(s)",
    "prato(s) de salada",
    "garrafa(s) de água",
    "refrigerante(s)"
  };

  for (cont = 0; cont < p; cont++) {
    int item = compra[cont][0];
    printf("\n %d %s;\n", 
    compra[cont][1], produto[item-1]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nossa! Muito obrigado. Acaba de funcionar. Como seria isso de memória dinâmica?

Comment: Usando `malloc` e `realloc` para ajustar aos novos tamanhos. Vê [isto](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/).